# How to plot a scatter plot calling pandas data frame series from a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I call two pandas dataframe series from a dictionary object (dataframe) and want to plot these in a scatter plot, but python sees my dataframe as an integer object.

I have checked that the value called from the dictionary is of the type: pandas.dataframe.series

Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2], [3,4]], columns = ['A', 'B'])

df = {'df1': df1}

for i in df.values():
    sns.scatterplot(x=i['A'], y = i['B'],  ax = 0)
```

I expect a scatter plot but receive the following error message:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'scatter'
```

Comment: are you sure the error comes from the posted piece of code? You might want to post the complete stacktrace and the code that produces `light` variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to reproduce the issue you mentioned with the below code

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2], [3,4]], columns = ['A', 'B'])
sns.scatterplot(x=df1['A'], y = df1['B'], ax = 0)
```

Output :
error
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'scatter'

The below code works just fine

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2], [3,4]], columns = ['A', 'B'])
sns.scatterplot(x=df1['A'], y = df1['B'])
```

If you want to pass ax as a parameter, this is not the correct way. ax should have axis object rather than an integer value .
Below code works with ax parameter

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2], [3,4]], columns = ['A', 'B'])
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(3,3))
sns.scatterplot(x=df1['A'], y = df1['B'],ax=ax)
```

Let me know if it does not resolve your issue

Comment: Thank you for the answer Akanksha. I had tried that, but received the following error: ```TypeError: string indices must be integers``` . I do not think one can call dictionary values in that way.

Comment: Hi, I have edited the question to provide an example. Perhaps omitting this is why I got a -1. I am relatively new to StackOverflow and am trying to learn the etiquette :|